# Struggling with json functions when argument is result of select

Tags: postgresql, json

I can find a plethora of examples for json_populate_recordset when the argument of json_populate_recordset(base anyelement, from_json json) is a text string such as:

```
select "values", "Type", "Name"  
from json_populate_recordset(null::contact2,'[{"Type":"Email","values":"kneal@someone.com","Name":"WorkEmail"},{"Type":"Email","values":"aneal@somewhere.com","Name":"WorkEmail"}]');
```

I can't find any help for when that argument is the result of a query such as:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json((SELECT ColumnName FROM (Select val, valtype, valname) as ColumnName ("Value","Type","Name")) )) as JsonData 
from contact ;
```

Comment: Your second query is invalid and it's unclear what you're intending to do. The parenthesized `(Select val, valtype, valname)` has no FROM. An example of the query results you see without the json_populate_recordset and the intended output would also be useful.

Comment: Where do the columns `val`, `valtype` and `valname` come from?